# ReactJS - Interpolation in a String and Not Render

Tags: html, reactjs

I have to render a token, which is very long. I don't want to render it, but instead have the below code with a clipboard icon next to it.

```
<p>Get your ${ID_TOKEN} here!</p>
```

How do I escape the interpolation? React keeps trying to render it as though I was trying to render a variable.

I already tried assigning a variable equal to a string of the interpolation.

```
const token = "${USER_TOKEN}"
```

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1545

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using ES6 and you mean to literally render '${ID_TOKEN}' you should be able to do:

```
<p>Get your ${`{ID_TOKEN}`} here!</p>
```

Super simple [DEMO](http://codepen.io/bullerb/pen/3116b29b147dfa52d5651607bfb95781)

Comment: One might use normal quotes in that case: `<p>Get your ${'{ID_TOKEN}'} here!</p>`

Comment: Quite possible I've been using too much ES6 lately